# How can multiple python servers on the same machine be made to interact with each other?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, implementation, distributed

I need to implement "**serial look-up**" and "**parallel look-up**" across a set of local servers. My servers are simple HTTP python server instances. **The local servers must be able to send updated data to other local servers**. Each local server knows about all the remaining local servers and the ports they are bound to. I need to know if this kind of communication is possible. If yes how? . Searching on the web results in mostly single server - multiple client architectures.

I am implementing a research paper and I need to compare the latency in serial and parallel look up in such a scenario.

edit 1: It does not need to be a HTTP server. It was easy to set up initially, thus it was chosen. Other alternatives are welcome

Comment: Do they _have_ to be http servers? Check out PyZMQ, which can do just about any kind of message passing.

Comment: Also note that nothing prevents a server to be a client of another server - that's typically what happens when a server app get or post data to/from an external webservice or rest api.

Comment: [Pyro4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4) is a good one to look into. You can create local name servers to each server instance so clients can lookup connections on the local network.